# Axios not using react proxy

Tags: reactjs

I'm at my wits end.

I'm creating a react app that connects to a express backend, as per the tutorial I am following I add the proxy to the package.json of the react app:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

However when I run a request with axios:

```
 const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });
  const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);
```

instead of calling localhost:5000/api/users it calls localhost:3000/api/users

I have even tried creating a axios instance:

```
const axIns = axios.create({
  proxy: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5000,
  },
});
```

Nothing works... please can you tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Could it be some middleware or any library that is intercepting the requests and modifying them ?

Comment: I'll poke around at get back to you :)

Comment: OK, so I just spun up a new app from create-react-app and installed axios, it still calls the client instead of the proxy

Comment: proxy (*as setup in the package.json*) is handled server side, so you would not see the requests in the browser going to `:5000`. They will go to `:3000` where the dev server is and it will route them to `:5000` and return the response.